# Is there a way to stop playing MP3 from another player instance of flash_mp3_player?

Tags: flash, mp3

Well this might be a lot to ask here, but I have been trying to do this for hours and can't get it to work....

First of all, I need to put multiple MP3 players on my webpage so I downloaded the player at http://flash-mp3-player.net/. I am using both the mini and the multi version... so when the mini starts playing, I want multi to shutup.

I thought the best way would be to modify the flash file to use localConnection and fire the stop function but I can't access the stop function at all... my code is like this

IN THE MINI templateA class:

```
public function playRelease()
    {       
        trace("playing clicked....test");
        var talkingLC:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
        talkingLC.send("simpleRequest_lc", "stopPlayingPls");
        this.player.play();
        if (this.player.getLoading().percent != 100) {
            this.startLoading();
        }
    }
```

And in the template MULTI's well... TemplateMulti.as constructor:

```
var listeningLC:LocalConnection = new LocalConnection();
        listeningLC.stopPlayingPls = function() {
            trace("Execute stopping routine "+this.parent._width);
            trace(MovieClip[this.parent]);
            /*stopRelease();
            super.stopRelease();
            this._enableButton(this._stopButtonInstance, false);
            this._enableButton(this._pauseButtonInstance, false, true);
            this._enableButton(this._playButtonInstance, true);
            delete this._sliderInstance.onEnterFrame;
            this._sliderInstance.bar_mc._x = 0;

            this.updatePlaylist();*/
        };
        listeningLC.connect("simpleRequest_lc");
```

Now I can get both the traces which means the localconnection works, and I can also write `this.stopRelease()` outside the listeningLC block....which works, but I can't access the `stopRelease()` function from within the `stopPlayingPls` function.

Oh and the trace with the `this` return `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use javascript, then the browser can make the connection to other swf instances. Continue the path you are on but take advantage of Flash's native ability to dispatch and listen for JS events in the browser.